# How is the security of a plaintext of Ring-LWE without an error term?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto

I think until public key $\mathsf{pk}=(b=-[as + e]_q,a) $ is broken, Ring-LWE is secure where $a$ is uniformaly random polynomial, $e$ is an error sampled from gaussian distribution with std=$\sigma$ and mean $\mu$=0, and $s$ is a secret key of hamming weight $h$.

$\mathbf{Question }$

Why is error needed for encryption?

A some Ring-LWE based homomorphic encryption schemes encrypts a message $m$ as  $\mathsf{ct}=([m+e_0+bv]_q,[av+e_1]_q)$ where

$q$: ciphertext space

$v$: uniformly random small polynomial

I wonder why $m+e_0+bv$ part needs $e_0$.
I think m+$bv$ is already uniform because $bv$ looks uniform.
So gaussian elimination cannot work here, isnt't it correct?

Comment: Is $p$ randomly chosen at each encryption? Do you have any link pointing to the paper that presents this scheme?

Comment: No. $p$ is fixed. $e_0$ and $e_1$ are randomly chosen every encryption time

Comment: Of course I understood the security of public key which encrypts the secret key by generating a ring-lwe instance, i.e.,  since $as$ is a constant, we need to add noise term. But as for the public-key-encryption part, because of unknown $bv$ with uniformly random $v$, $m+bv$ already looks uniform. Why is it to be $m+bv+e_0$ with additional noise term?

Comment: But if no error term $e_0$ were added, what would you get if you calculated $ct[0] \pmod b$?